# Cannot bundle gem factory_girl_rails into rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Following this post [Factory Girl](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/19412394597/factory-girl-hits-3-0)

> If you can’t upgrade to Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3, you can continue to use factory_girl_rails version 1.x and FactoryGirl 2.x; those will continue to support Ruby 1.8.7+ and Rails 2.3.9+.

I am trying to set up factory girl into Rails 2.3.14 with Ruby 1.8.7 but still cant bundle:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    factory_girl_rails (= 1.0.0) ruby depends on
      rails (>= 3.0.0.beta4) ruby

    rails (2.3.14)
```

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
source "http://gems.github.com"
gem "rails", "2.3.14"
gem "rspec", "1.2.6"
gem "rspec-rails", "1.2.6"
gem "factory_girl_rails", "1.0.0"
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to do the same setup as you, but `factory_girl_rails` depends on Rails 3 since version 1.0 according to the dependencies section in
https://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl_rails/versions/1.0

Your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
source :rubygems
group :development, :test do
  gem "factory_girl", "2.6.4"
  gem "rspec", "1.3.2", :require => false
  gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.4", :require => false
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara", "1.1.1"
  gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

What factory_girl_rails do, basically, is to set the fixture_replacement option (I don't think exist in Rails 2.3), the factories paths and setup the generators.

I guess we'll have to adapt the code in here https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb to make it work for Rails 2.3 by tweaking Rspec and Cucumber config files.

Answer (score 0):

you could try change your Gemfile this: 
`source :rubygems` 
`source "http://gems.github.com"`

for this 
`source 'http://rubygems.org'`